# In Windows 10, is there a way to display the time remaining when backing up files?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-backup, file-history

**Question:** When using File History to back up my files in Windows 10 (or 8/8.1) is there a way to display how much time is remaining until the backup completes? Or any display of progress what so ever?

Currently, all I can see is the following:

[image: File back-up]

Note: I've read:

[How to show progress of "File History" in Windows8?](https://superuser.com/questions/496224/how-to-show-progress-of-file-history-in-windows8?rq=1)

But since it was asked for **Windows 8 in 2012** and the fact that the answer is essentially, *no there is not a way.* I'm leaving my question up to see if there's been any addition of the feature I'm looking for.

Comment: use 3rd party tools like Macrium Reflect: http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 Not a bad idea, thank you.